# How do you handle graphql query and fragment in python?

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql, fragment

I am trying to query using the requests library but am having trouble. I suspect it's to do with the handling of the fragment but I'm not sure.

When I run the code I get Response 400. Here is my code:

```
import requests
import json

query = """query GetAxieTransferHistory($axieId: ID!, $from: Int!, $size: Int!) {
  axie(axieId: $axieId) {
    id
    transferHistory(from: $from, size: $size) {
      ...TransferRecords
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}

fragment TransferRecords on TransferRecords {
  total
  results {
    from
    to
    timestamp
    txHash
    withPrice
    __typename
  }
  __typename
}"""

params = {
  "axieId": "9082310",
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1
}

url = 'https://axieinfinity.com/graphql-server-v2/graphql'

r = requests.post(url, json={"query": query, "params": params})
print(r.status_code)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `params` key to `variables`

`r = requests.post(url, json={"query": query, "variables": params})`

Comment: @MaxB, Welcome to SO! If an answer helps you in solving your problem, you should consider upvoting and accepting it. This way you can both help the fellow developers looking for the solution to their problem and kind of "reward" the author of answer